# Curl контент поместить в массив php

Tags: php, curl

Всем привет, имеется информация полученная через CURL с содержимым:
login=Вася Пупкин city=Москва tel=0 123 456 567 sex=male

Как мне правильно разбить её на массив для дальнейшей работы с данными?
На данный момент у меня есть вот такой код, но почему то я не могу его пропустить через forech: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Я так понимаю это из за того, что полученная информация передается не в массиве.

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url) { 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Justice.ru");
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $data; 
} 

$lines = file_get_contents_curl('http://emeraldscity.combats.ru/inf.pl?short=1327641470');
foreach($lines as $value)
        { 
                list($var, $val) = explode('=',$value); 
                $arr[$var] = $val; 
        }
echo $arr[login];
?>
```

Comment: Ваша функция `file_get_contents_curl()` возвращает строку, а не массив. Чтобы разбить ее на строки можно воспользоваться, например `explode`. Но в вашем случае лучше подойдет регулярка

Answer (score -1):

Первый вариант с проверкой

```
$result = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $lines);
foreach($result as $value){
  if($value != ''){
    list($var, $val) = explode('=',$value);
    $arr[$var] = $val;
  }
}
```

Второй вариант. Можно сразу в preg_split указать, чтобы пропускались пустые строки

```
$result = preg_split('/\n|\r/', $lines, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach($result as $value)
{
  list($var, $val) = explode('=',$value);
  $arr[$var] = $val;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению такой вариант не подходит, так как в значении может быть слово с пробелом на пример login=Вася Пупкин